# Is there a site that will scan my website and check it for security holes?

Tags: security, website

Is there a site that will scan my website and check it for security holes?

Preferably one that doesn't charge.

Comment: I highly doubt it... at least not one that is well-intentioned. And especially not free. Instead, you should hire a developer who knows how to check for these things.

Comment: This is probably better asked on Stackoverflow (if you're the site's developer) or Serverfault (if you're the site's admin).

Comment: Good question, but doesn't belong on Super User.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [WebScarab](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project).

> WebScarab is a framework for analysing
>   applications that communicate using
>   the HTTP and HTTPS protocols. It is
>   written in Java, and is thus portable
>   to many platforms. WebScarab has
>   several modes of operation,
>   implemented by a number of plugins. In
>   its most common usage, WebScarab
>   operates as an intercepting proxy,
>   allowing the operator to review and
>   modify requests created by the browser
>   before they are sent to the server,
>   and to review and modify responses
>   returned from the server before they
>   are received by the browser. WebScarab
>   is able to intercept both HTTP and
>   HTTPS communication. The operator can
>   also review the conversations
>   (requests and responses) that have
>   passed through WebScarab.

Vulnerability assessment in web applications and web sites is not common available for free, and usually involves hiring a security consultant/researcher.

Comment: The firefox plug in tamperdata fits the common usage; not to mention IE's fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

I [asked about Web Vuln scanners](https://serverfault.com/questions/45717/web-application-vulnerability-scanner-suggestions) over on Server Fault recently. The only hosted option that was suggested was [WebsiteOptimization.com's Security service](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/services/security/). I haven't tried it yet, but they do offer a 14 day freebie.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ShieldsUp by Gibson Research](http://www.grc.com).

I've used it in the past and it is free.

Comment: I believe this one is for personal computers, not web-sites

Answer (score 0):

There are some, but the free ones don't really tell you anything useful. I have personally yet to [find](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=sql+injection+test) a tool that fuzzes the input fields of every form and tests for sql vulnerabilities that seems... [reput](http://www.acunetix.com/vulnerability-scanner/sql-injection-scanner.htm)[able](http://www.zubrag.com/tools/sql-injection-test.php). You sort of are best off doing this stuff by hand and going through a [check list](http://databases.about.com/od/security/a/sql_inject_test.htm).